# Can you migrate heroku databases between apps using forking?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

We have a production database, and we'd like to take regular snapshots of it to our staging database.

I know how to do this using pgbackups, I was wondering if anyone knows how to do it with the new HerokuPostgres fork function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can create a fork from directly from one applications DB to another. To do this get the value for your DATABASE_URL from your primary application then use it in the below command:

```
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:ronin --fork postgres://username:password@ec2.../database --app yourstagingapp
```

Comment: To get the postgres:// url, run $ heroku config and grab the DATABASE_URL line (or HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_color_URL)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Craig's answer, here's [a script by freeformz](https://gist.github.com/3374606) which does the whole job.

```
app=${1}
db_type=${2:-ronin}

old_db=`heroku config -a ${app}-staging | grep ^HEROKU_POSTGRESQL | cut -d : -f 1 | sed s/_URL//`
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:${db_type} --fork `heroku config -a ${app} | grep ^DATABASE_URL | cut -d : -f 2-5` -a ${app}-staging
new_db=`heroku config -a ${app}-staging | grep ^HEROKU_POSTGRESQL | grep -v ${old_db} | cut -d : -f 1 | sed s/_URL//`
heroku pg:wait -a ${app}-staging
heroku pg:promote ${new_db} -a ${app}-staging
#Remove the old db
if [ ! -z "${old_db}" ]l; then
  heroku addons:remove ${old_db} -a ${app}-staging --confirm ${app}-staging
fi
```